# prove by induction $\sqrt{1 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3.....\sqrt n }}} < 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

My attempt:

let $$p(n-1) = \sqrt{1 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3.....\sqrt{n-1} }}}$$

now let us assume that $p(n-1)$ is less than 2

for $n = 1$(base case)
$ \sqrt 1 = 1 < 2$

now $$\frac{p(n)}{p(n-1)}  = \frac{\sqrt{1 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3.....\sqrt{n}}}}}{ \sqrt{1 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3.....\sqrt{n-1} }}})} = n^{(1/2^n)}$$

now

$$\sqrt{1 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3.....\sqrt n }}} < \sqrt{1 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3.....\sqrt{n-1}  }}} \cdot n^{(1/2^n)} $$

as $p(n-1)$ is less than 2 so we can write

$$\sqrt{1 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3.....\sqrt n }}} < 2n^{(1/2^n)} $$

as n tends to infinity $2n^{(1/2^n)}$ converges to 2 so by taking limits on both sides we have

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \sqrt{1 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3.....\sqrt n }}} < 2$$

now $\frac{p(n)}{p(n-1)}$ equals $n^{(1/2^n)}$ which is always greater than 1 this means that $p(n)$ is strictly increasing. So if p(n) is increasing and $\lim_{{n \to \infty}} p(n) $ < 2 then this means that p(n) is always lesser than 2 for all n.

This was my argument, but I wasn't given credit for this solution. So is there anything wrong with my solution.

Comment: I think you have to show boundedness.

Comment: @Diger I agree, but the only credit I got for this question was for mentioning the base case.

Comment: Your proof seems a bit odd to me, because you use induction AND a limit for $n\to\infty$. You can‘t do that. If you want your proof to be somehow correct, you can not say „ assume that … for some $n$ is true. Now let $n$ go to infinity.“, because that is not allowed.

Comment: Do you have to use induction?

Comment: @ Eric may have written it weirdly, but what I wanted to say was that p(n) is bounded above by 2. Since p(n) is implied from p(n-1), the induction step is complete.

Comment: @Diger, yes, we were required to use induction.

Comment: Your proof method could also suggest $\sqrt{2}\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt[4]{2}\sqrt[5]{2}\cdots <2$ since the initial term is $\sqrt{2}<2$ and the ratio is $\sqrt[n-1]{2} \to 1$, but it is not correct since $\sqrt{2}\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt[4]{2} \approx 2.1189$

Comment: @Henry, I believe I am doing something different. I am saying that p(n) is always less than 2. Now p(n)/p(n-1) is always greater than 1. Then p(n-1) is always less than 2.

Comment: But "$p(n)$ is always less than $2$" is what you wanted to prove in the first place.

Comment: @aschepler Sorry for an inaccurate comment. What I meant was that since p(n) as n tends to infinity is less than 2 and since p(n) is strictly increasing this proves that p(n) is less than 2 for all n.

Comment: I think your idea is technically correct, but you haven't proven $p(\infty)<2$ using induction.

Comment: You say *"since $p(n)$ as $n$ tends to infinity is less than $2$ and ... this proves that $p(n)$ is less than $2$ for all $n$"* which is not induction but assuming the result.

Comment: @Henry, But I came up with this result using induction, so maybe I am indirectly using induction to prove it?

Comment: @Henry: Maybe he means backwards induction. If $p(\infty)<2$ then, since $p(n)$ is increasing, $p(n)<2$ for all $n<\infty$.

Comment: @Mathking If you change $p(n)$ to be $p(n) = \sqrt{2} \sqrt[3]{2} \cdots \sqrt[n]{2}$ as Henry suggests, what in your proof is no longer true?

Comment: You do not know $p(\infty)<2$ (presumably interpreted as a limit). Better would be to say something like: the inductive hypothesis is that $p(n) < 2^{1-2^{3-n}}$ for $n \ge 5$, and from this it is possible to prove $p(n+1) < 2^{1-2^{3-(n+1)}}$ and we can show $p(5) < 2^{3/4}$ as a starting point

Comment: Your first lines seem incorrect to me. In short you said
$$"\text{now } p(n) = p(n-1) \cdot n^{(1/2^n)}"$$
$$"\text{now } p(n) < p(n-1) \cdot n^{(1/2^n)}"$$
and then continued the reasoning as if everything was ok, but both statements above are a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in going from

$$ p(n) = \sqrt{1 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3.....\sqrt n }}} < 2n^{(1/2^n)} $$

to

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} p(n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{1 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3.....\sqrt n }}} < \lim_{n \to \infty} 2n^{(1/2^n)} $$

Remember the context: you were assuming for now that $p(n-1) < 2$. So you have correctly proved that

$$ p(n-1) < 2 \implies p(n) < 2n^{(1/2^n)} $$

But this doesn't tell us for example that $p(n+1) < 2(n+1)^{(1/2^{n+1})}$. Assuming that $p(n-1)<2$ can only tell us that $p(n+1) < 2n^{(1/2^n)}(n+1)^{(1/2^{n+1})}$.

To make the limit comparison valid, you would need to know that $p(n) < 2n^{(1/2^n)}$ for every $n$ (or for every $n>N$).

This proof approach is not easy to fix. Maybe it would work to inductively show $p(n) < q(n)$ for some formula $q$ where it's more obvious $q(n)<2$ for every $n$.

Comment: I don't think he proved correctly that $p(n) < 2n^{ (1/2^n)} $. First he stated that
$$\frac{p(n)}{p(n-1)}  = \frac{\sqrt{1 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3.....\sqrt{n}}}}}{ \sqrt{1 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3.....\sqrt{n-1} }}})} = n^{(1/2^n)}$$ 
and from this he jumped to the conclusion that
$$\sqrt{1 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3.....\sqrt n }}} < \sqrt{1 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{3.....\sqrt{n-1}  }}} \cdot n^{(1/2^n)} $$
which is the same as 
$$  p(n) < p(n-1)  \cdot n^{(1/2^n)}.$$
This contradicts the first equality 
$$p(n) = p(n-1) \cdot n^{(1/2^n)} $$
given at the begining.

Comment: @Integral I did miss that. It reads like I thought if the one $<$ is replaced with $=$.

Answer (score 5):

Passing to log we have to show that
$$ S=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\log n}{2^{n}}<\log 2.
\ \ $$ The trick is to use the majorization for $n\geq 2$ $$\log n\leq \frac{n}{2}+\log 2 -1$$ leading to $S<\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\log 2.$ You have to use $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nz^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ applied to $z=1/2.$

Comment: This is a nice solution, except that it doesn't use induction. I don't see what the intended proof with induction would be, though.

Answer (score 1):

In the induction step you show $p(n) < 2*2^{1 \over 2^n}$. Then you insert $p(n) < 2$ into the next step when you are have that $p(n+1) < 2*2^{1 \over 2^{n+1}}$. This is not a valid argument since you are inserting a better statement than what you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

**First Version:**
You said you need to use induction. So assume that
$$S_n=\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{\log k}{2^k} < \log 2 - \frac cn$$
for some $n$ and $c$. Going to $n+1$
$$S_{n+1} < \log 2 - \frac cn + \frac{\log(n+1)}{2^{n+1}} \stackrel{!}{\leq} \log 2 - \frac{c}{n+1}$$
and so $c$ must satisfy
$$f(n)=\frac{n(n+1)\log(n+1)}{2^{n+1}} \leq c \, .$$
We have $f(3)=\frac{3\log 2}{2}>f(4)=\frac{5\log5}{8}$
and
$$f'(n)=\frac{\left(-(n^2+n)\log2+2n+1\right)\log(n+1)+n}{2^{n+1}} \\
\leq -\frac{\log(n+1)}{2^{n+1}} \, \left[(n^2+n)\log2-3n-1\right] \\
=-\frac{\log(n+1)\log2}{2^{n+1}}\left[\left(n-\frac{3/\log2-1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{3/\log2-1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{\log2}\right] \, .$$
Now if $n\geq \frac{3/\log2-1}{2}$, the square bracket is an increasing function in $n$ and for $n=4>\frac{3/\log2-1}{2}$ we have
$$f'(4)=-\frac{\log5}{32}\left[20\log2-13\right]<0 \, ,$$
thus $f'(n)<0$ for all $n\geq 4$, which in turn implies $f(3)>f(4)>f(5)>...$.

We can therefore choose $c=f(3)=\frac{3\log2}{2}$ and our induction step is fulfilled for every $n\geq 3$. It remains to check the induction start, that is $n=3$,
$$\frac{\log2}{4}+\frac{\log3}{8} < \frac{\log2}{4} + \frac{\log4}{8} = \frac{\log2}{2} = \log 2 - \frac{\frac{3\log2}{2}}{3} \, .$$

The case $n=2$ can be checked separately i.e. $\log2/4 < \log2$, which is clearly true.

---

**Second Version:**
I just realized it is probably much easier to make the ansatz
$$S_n < \log2 - \frac{cn}{2^n}$$
which gives rise to the induction step
$$S_{n+1} = S_n + \frac{\log(n+1)}{2^{n+1}} < \log 2 - \frac{cn}{2^n} + \frac{\log(n+1)}{2^{n+1}} \stackrel{!}{\leq} \log 2 - \frac{c(n+1)}{2^{n+1}}$$
i.e. the condition
$$c \geq \frac{\log(n+1)}{n-1}=f(n)$$
which is true for every $n\geq 3$, since
$$f'(n)=\frac{-(n+1)\log(n+1)+n-1}{(n+1)(n-1)^2} < \frac{-(n+1)\log(e)+n-1}{(n+1)(n-1)^2} = -\frac{2}{(n+1)(n-1)^2} < 0$$
for every $n\geq 2$ and if $c=f(3)=\log 2$ (which is the maximal value for all $n\geq 3$, while the induction start for $n=2$ wouldn't work). The induction start is then again $n=3$ i.e.
$$\log 2 - \frac{3\log 2}{8} > \log 2 - \frac{4\log 2}{8} = \frac{\log 2}{2} = \frac{\log 2}{4} + \frac{\log 4}{8} > \frac{\log 2}{4} + \frac{\log 3}{8} = S_3 \, .$$